# Induction Outset

Tags: analysis, induction

I am referring to this older question, which I found here for preparation:

[Proof by induction that $\sum_{j=0}^n 2^j = 2^{n+1} - 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/761156/proof-by-induction-that-sum-j-0n-2j-2n1-1)

Could somebody outline the Induction outset and the goal?
I am unsure where to put in my (n + 1).
My approach would be:
`2⁰ - 1 + 2^(n+1) -1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base case $n=0$:  $\sum\limits_{j=0}^0 2^j=2^{1}-1$.

Inductive step:  assuming $\sum\limits_{j=0}^n 2^j=2^{n+1}-1$, show that $\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n\color{blue}{+1}} 2^j=2^{(n\color{blue}{+1})+1}-1$.

(Put $n\color{blue}{+1}$ wherever $n$ appeared.)

Comment: Alright, I got the very last part. This is my goal. But how do I start? So what does the sum sign on the left say?

Comment: Note that $\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n\color{blue}{+1}} 2^j=2^{n+1}+\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n } 2^j$

Comment: and where is the "-1" in this?

Comment: That would mean: 2^(n+1) + 2^(n+2) -1 ?

Comment: That would mean $2^{n+1}+2^{n+1}-1$, which is $2^{n+2}-1$, q.e.d.

Comment: And a step in between would be 4^(n+1)-1 = 2^(n+2) - 1?

Comment: No, it would be $2^{n+1}+2^{n+1}= 2^{n+1}2=2^{n+1}2^1=2^{n+1+1}=2^{n+2}$

Answer (score 0):

Generalise:
$$1+x+x^2+\dots +x^n=\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}.$$
This formula is the simplest nontrivial model when one teaches proofs by induction.

The inductive step begins with
\begin{align}
1+x+x^2+\dots+x^{n+1}&=(1+x+x^2+\dots +x^n)+x^{n+1}\\
&=\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}+x^{n+1}=\dots
\end{align}

Comment: I would basically need the meaning of the sum sign as I am unsure about the power of j

Comment: @Luise: it means  what's on the left side of the first equation of my answer, with $2$ in the place of $x$ – you add all powers of $2$, from $0$ to the $n$-th power.