# Proof by induction (exponents)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

> Use proof by induction and show that the formula holds for all positive integers:$$1+3+3^2+\dots+3^{n-1}=\frac{3^n -1}2$$

The confusing step in my opinion is the first expression: $3^{n-1}$, when I have to show for $k+1$. Any solutions?

Comment: Is this really algebra-precalculus?

Comment: See the second answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22599/how-do-i-prove-this-by-induction-sum-of-powers-of-2/

Comment: @Shahar Well, it's not calculus! But yes, I guess it'd appear in algebra $2$ in high school.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar Not really calculus but I didn't learn this in algebra either. What should I tag this?

Comment: alright, so I guess I get 3^(k-1)+1) which is 3^k? @user133281

Comment: @Shahar I believe there's an induction tag. Oh wait, Ivo Terek already edited it. Never mind!

Comment: you equality is wrong !! For $n=0$, $n=1$... try, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Shahar : Nothing is "algebra-precalculus".  The tag should be abolished.  Tags should be about subject matter, not about where something is located in a curriculum.  Curricula are evil.

Comment: @Shahar : I think of this as a standard part of high-school math that is covered before one gets to calculus, but in in "our" present "system" (ok, maybe it is in some respects a system) that means 99% of those who've gone through that course will never have heard of it.

Comment: @MichaelHardy What about stuff like $\cos(x)+3=2$?

Comment: What about it? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Is that under the Common Core or something? I never learned this in algebra class.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I meant what would you classify a question like that, it incorporates both algebra and precalculus.

Comment: @Shahar : I have no idea what the content of "common core" is.  I have the impression it's about prescribing that all humans should learn the same things at the same ages.  That is evil.

Comment: @MichaelHardy All students of the United States, if that makes it less evil ^_^.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Show $3^{1-1}=\dfrac{3^1-1}{2}$
2. Assume $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}3^k=\dfrac{3^n-1}{2}$
3. Prove $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}3^k=\dfrac{3^{n+1}-1}{2}$:

   - $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}3^k=(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}3^k)+3^n$
   - $(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}3^k)+3^n=\dfrac{3^n-1}{2}+3^n$
   - $\dfrac{3^n-1}{2}+3^n=\dfrac{3^n-1+2\cdot3^n}{2}$
   - $\dfrac{3^n-1+2\cdot3^n}{2}=\dfrac{3^n+2\cdot3^n-1}{2}$
   - $\dfrac{3^n+2\cdot3^n-1}{2}=\dfrac{3\cdot3^n-1}{2}$
   - $\dfrac{3\cdot3^n-1}{2}=\dfrac{3^{n+1}-1}{2}$

Note that the induction-step is applied **only** at the second bullet.

Comment: wow nice, could you please explain the second last line? thanks

Comment: @gger234: I added a line explaining that; hope it helps...

Comment: @gger234: Note that the induction step takes place **only** at the second bullet of section 2.

Comment: @gger234: $X+2\cdot{X}=3X$

Comment: (Don't you also want to include the case $n=1$?)

Comment: @user84413: OP asked for help, not for a complete proof.

Comment: Okay, I just wanted to make sure that the OP realized that was needed.

Comment: @user84413: Added that just in case. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $x \neq 1$. We wish to show by inducting on $n$ that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}x^{k} = \frac{x^{n} - 1}{x-1}$.

Then $1 = \frac{x-1}{x-1}$ so that the formula holds for $n = 1$. 
Suppose that we have $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}x^{k} = \frac{x^{n} - 1}{x-1}$. We must show that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}x^{k} = \frac{x^{n+1} - 1}{x-1}$.

We have $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}x^{k} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n- 1}x^{k} + x^{n} = \frac{x^{n} - 1}{x-1} + x^{n}\frac{x -1}{x-1} = \frac{x^{n} - 1 + x^{n+1} - x^{n}}{x - 1} = \frac{x^{n+1} - 1}{x-1}$

Answer (score 0):

For n+1 it is

$1+3+3^2+\ldots+3^{n-1}+3^n=\frac{3^{n+1}-1}{2}$

$\left( 1+3+3^2+\ldots +3^{n-1}\right) +3^n=\frac{3\cdot 3^{n}-1}{2}$

$\left( 1+3+3^2+\ldots +3^{n-1}\right) +3^n=\frac{(1+2)\cdot 3^{n}-1}{2}$

$\left( 1+3+3^2+\ldots +3^{n-1}\right) +3^n=\frac{1\cdot 3^{n}-1}{2}+\frac{2\cdot 3^{n}}{2}$

$\left( 1+3+3^2+\ldots +3^{n-1}\right) +3^n=\left( \frac{1\cdot 3^{n}-1}{2}\right) + 3^n$

Answer (score 0):

For the base case simply show that the premise is true for the smallest positive integer: $\mathsf P(1)$.

For the iterative case, you have to show that if the premise holds for $n$, then it is implied to hold for $n+1$.   $\mathsf P(n)\implies\mathsf P(n+1)$

Do that by substituting $n+1$ for $n$ and demonstrate that the left and right hand side both contain terms of the original premise and the same modifier.

Here we show that modifier is the addition of $3^n$.

$\begin{align}
\text{Prove }\forall n\in \mathbb Z^+: \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 3^k & = \frac {3^n-1}{2} & \text{premise }
\\[3ex]
3^0 & = \frac{3^1-1}{2} & \text{base case} 
\\[3ex]
 3^n + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 3^k & = \sum_{k=0}^{n} 3^k 
\\[1ex] 3^n+\frac {3^n-1}{2} & = \frac{3\cdot 3^n-1}{2} 
\\[2ex] \therefore 
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 3^k & = \frac {3^n-1}{2} \implies  \sum_{k=0}^{n} 3^k = \frac{3^{n+1}-1}{2} &\text{iterative step }
\\[2ex]\therefore \forall n\in\mathbb Z^+: \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 3^k & = \frac {3^n-1}{2} & \text{by induction}
\end{align}$